# How to clear the unused space in fuseki

Tags: sparql, fuseki

Observed a behaviour associated with fuseki that, even after dropping the graphs from a fuseki dataset (using DROP GRAPH command), the actual size of the folder "run/databases" is  not decreasing. Recently read about the backup and restore mechanism to solve this issue, and just wanted to know if any alternative approach is also available for the same. Also, Is this size issue happens in fuseki 3x versions? I've observed this in fuseki 2.4.0 version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it depends on the TDB version you chose, TDB1 or TDB2 - but the node table isn't pruned during DELETE directly. So reload the data would result in the most compact disk space usage. For example `tdbloader2` creates a very compact B+ tree, later changes make it more fragmented on disk. By the way, latest version is `4.2.0` ...

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue, my db from 2.3 was at 50GB, and then I reloaded into 4.3 and it blew up to 180GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer relates to the current Apache Jena Fuseki - version 4.2.0.

TDB2 has a compaction tool (only run this when Fuseki is not running). `tdb2.compact`

Or, depending on your setup, `curl -XPOST http://server:port/$/compact/<datasetname>` will compact a database in a running server.

Comment: Thanks @AndyS - compaction helped me in decreasing the database size. Now I have two databases, the compact one, which is live and the another one, which is not going to be used anymore and can be deleted. So everytime when I perform a compact operation, do I need to delete the old database folder manually or do we have any command to take care of this deletion?

Also, I've upgraded fuseki from 2x to 4x version, and observed each update operation (including DROP GRAPH command) gradually increases the database size. May I know, why this is happening in 4x version and not in 2x ?

Comment: It happens in all versions. Can't explain why you didn't see it in 2.4.0 unless that version was not providing full transaction features (2.4.0 was a long time ago). You can delete the old database, or zip it up and delete it.(On MS windows, it won't free the disk space completely because of a long term Java/Windows issue in the JDK.)

Comment: I get an error when running curl -XPOST http://server:port/$/compact/<datasetname> on 4.3: 
:: Task : 1 : Compact
19:01:54 INFO  Server          :: [Task 1] starts : Compact
19:01:54 INFO  Compact         :: [33772] >>>> Start compact /ds
19:01:58 WARN  Compact         :: [33772] **** Exception in compact
org.apache.jena.tdb2.TDBException: NodeTableTRDF/Read

Comment: Not enough of the error and stack trace showing. Look down the stacktrace for the "caused by". There may be several, the last, furthest down, is usually the most relevant.

Comment: Thanks @AndyS: Here's one `Caused by: org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Unrecognized type 0`

Here's the full print out: https://gist.github.com/jeffreycwitt/e7c270aae46f403845c87aa57e4b82af

Comment: Looks like the database is corrupt in some way. Not related to the compaction (this ticket) but already bad. Try a backup but I think another process interfere at some time in the past.

Comment: @AndyS Rebuilt it more slowly and succeeded! Many thanks.

Comment: @AndyS I've tried the backup and restore method to clear the unused space in fuseki.. It works as expected if only few datasets are there in fuseki, but when I tried the same for about 200+ datasets, using an iterative script, it is always getting stuck after completing the backup of around 20+ datasets(nearly 1-1.5GB). Any specific reason for this? Any constraint on the total folders size that the run/backup folder can accommodate?

Comment: There are no built-in limits. Obvious OS limits apply, see `ulimit` settings. But generally these cause errors not stalling. Is it always the same place? Is there enough disk space? Are you trying to do in parallel or one at a time? The other cause of stalling effects is that the JVM is trying to GC and is very close to running out. This can be seen as high CPU with multiple threads at 100%.